# How to remove clear coat drips?

Tags: paint

I have sanded, applied primer and then spraypainted my bicycle. Then I sprayed clear coat on it. This last step ruined my bike. The clear coat was dripping all over the bicycle frame.

How can I smooth this out? Could I use sandpaper with 1200 grit size and then reapply the clear coat on the sanded areas?

I rather not sand down the entire bike and start all over again starting with primer.

Comment: You could VERY CAREFULLY sand away the blobs (be careful not to sand through to the paint), then re-coat.  May not produce the perfect finish, though.

Answer (score 1):

As per Daniels' suggestion try sanding the rough spots.Before repainting try to figure out what went wrong the first time,was it to humid outside,did the nozzle glog during application,did you apply it too thick?Painting round surfaces can be difficult.Try applying several light coats while allowing it to dry between applications,follow the instructions on the can for drying times.Practice your spray technique on some scrap pipe or backyard fence to get your arm movement consistant.Pay particular attention to complex areas like the bottom bracket area where many pieces and angles are involved,it may take several passes at odd angles to get complete coverage without runs and sags.

Comment: Yep, and you generally should cover the hardest-to-reach areas first, then hit the easier areas.  You often have a problem of getting too much on the "easy" areas you've already covered while covering the hard-to-reach areas.